Change url to file path
I have a form on my CPanel. The url show the path to the file the form is located (website.com/folder/subfolder/file-name). I want to change this url to something else (website.com/new-url).  I tried the code below, but when I type website.com/new-url directly into the address box, it doesn't show the form.
window.history.replaceState('', '', '/new-url');


You should handle this in your server using rewrite url. So find for how to rewrite url based on your server side programing language and web server. This is not in javascript inention.
